# Why do some commits are ignored?

Tags: git, azure-devops

Here is my issue, someone did a merge action(maybe), which cause some commits are ignored in the git repository of my project(in VSO). Can someone let me know, why this happens, and how can it happen?

My project has only one branch 'develop' in VSO, below are histories in order

A->B->C->D->E->F->G

B,C,F are committed by UserA, F is merge action(checked, this commit contains no changes), D, E are committed by some other users, there are no code conflict between commits B,C,F, and D,E. as all changes are in completely different files. here is the problem, when pull latest code, the code changes in commits A,B,C,F,G are appeared in local disk, but D,E are not.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Cube, It looks like either F or G overwrote the changes from D and E. This happens often when users do not use expected Git workflow and don't Pull all changes before they work on code or commit code.

[image]

You should be abale to verify this by looking at the diff of D->F or D->G to see which commit overwrite the changes.

Comment: It's not the situation. in VSO file(changed in D) histories, there is a filter options, if i choose 'Simple history (default)', then commits D and E are not in list, but if i choose 'Full hisotry' then there are in the list. Is it possible that these files' head(latest) version are reset to its old version?

Answer (score 0):

For your workaround, it usually caused by this situation:
The other developer worked on a branch (we call it temp here), and then it merged into develop branch.

```
A---B---C-------F---G   develop
         \     /
          D---E         temp
```

When you pull change to local, select develop branch -> view history. If you select **show first parent only**, so you will find the history for develop branch as :

```
A---B---C-------F---G   develop
```

[image]